# Is it essential to read Saussure's Course in General Linguistics to fully engage with Lévi-Strauss?

Tags: structuralism

I'm already familiar with the general idea presented in the book, but I really want to read Lévi-Strauss' Structural Anthropology right now. If I not read Saussure, will i miss something in Lévi-Strauss arguments/thesis?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: i've read it, and still don't understand levi-strauss. i hate post-structuralists, and never get them

Comment: Can be useful, [The Cambridge Companion to Lévi-Strauss (2009)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Cambridge_Companion_to_L%C3%A9vi_Strauss/7NQhAwAAQBAJ) as well as [The Cambridge Companion to Saussure (2004)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Cambridge_Companion_to_Saussure/KRy-xWG1MvIC)

Answer (score 1):

*Structural Anthropology* is actually a collection of articles, published between 1945 and 1956. The index lists 5 mentions of Saussure, three of them in a later postscript to Chap.2-3, dealing with the arbitrariness of language signs. You don't *need* to read his book but you might miss becoming acquainted with a truly remarkable text.

Comment: oh, don't worry! i will definitively read saussure's work one day. thanks for the answer!